# Multiple VirtualizedLists and ScrollViews warning

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, mobile-development, react-native-scrollview

Currently there is a screen with the following schema:

```
<ScrollView>
  <Header>
  <FlatList> // virtualized

  <Header>
  <FlatList> // virtualized

  <Header>
  <FlatList> // virtualized

  ...
</ScrollView>
```

*<Header>* is just a header-alike stylized text.

It naturally gives a warning:

> VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with
> the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed container
> instead.

There is a nice-working solution for a single list:

> [React-Native another VirtualizedList-backed container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58243680/react-native-another-virtualizedlist-backed-container)

**Q.** But how to deal with multiple lists like in the schema above?

Comment: Did you already try to use SectionList? https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist

Comment: Looks like a nice way to go.

Comment: @IanVasco Am I right that there is no generic solution for multiple scrollable multi nested lists? It's either FlatList/SectionList or ScrollView wrapper with the warning and associated performance issues?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Using SectionList is the best option to go, you might need to change your data a little bit but is far better than having a ScrollView wrapper