# How to check if a Scroll View has reached it top in React Native?

Tags: react-native

Hello guys I am creating a chat app using React Native. And in chat screen which is the core feature obviously as you know we have to scroll towards the top to load more messages. I am using Scroll View to show messages. Is there any way that I can check if the Scroll View has reached its top ( not bottom )?
Thanks!

Comment: do you mean like in the gmail app where you can scroll past the top to refresh?

Comment: @GiladShnoor No, like whatsapp in which you scroll to top to load more message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FlatList for rendering Chats this will improve your performance over ScrollView. [Flatlist vs ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55256221/flatlist-vs-scrollview/55256341#:%7E:text=3%20Answers&text=ScrollView%20will%20load%20items%20(data,scrolling)%20immediately%20after%20component%20loading.&text=But%20FlatList%20has%20a%20better,of%20FlatList%20instead%20of%20ScrollView.)

Use [inverted](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#inverted) prop of Flatlist to invert it. And after that use [onEndReached](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onendreached) prop in that call your loadMoreMessage function.
When your FlatList is inverted your onEndReached would be called when you reach the top.

Comment: Thanks and I have this example on Github: https://github.com/jefelewis/react-native-infinite-scroll-demo

Comment: could you give a small example as to how to invert and add onEndReached ? @rishikesh_07

Comment: Also if my flatlist is inverted, isn't it that the new messages will also come on top, and the old one below?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a chat app that has an unknown amount of chats you should be using a `flatlist` in order to display them. It will save you a lot of memory.
Flat list also has this functionality built in take a look at onRefresh:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onrefresh

Comment: Thanks and I have this example on Github: https://github.com/jefelewis/react-native-infinite-scroll-demo