# Swipe to next screen (infinite)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, swipe, react-native-gesture-handler

I have a calendar section in my app where I want to be able to swipe right or left to go to the next or previous day.

I know that you can use `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` from React Navigation to do something similar, but I'm not sure if it would work in this specific scenario (where I would have an infinite number of screens and wouldn't be able to predefine them).

I also considered using `react-native-gesture-handler`'s `Swipeable` component to navigate to the next/previous day screen on a left/right swipe but I'm not sure if this is the easiest/best way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, you can use `Tabs` or `Swipable`. There are some other options like using `<ifaram>` or `<WebView>` and using a web URL instead of RN components but it's can be tricky and hard to manipulate.

As a simple solution, you can use `carousels` instead of using multi `screen` defining navigation. It's very simple. assume that your screens are an image in an image gallery and you can swipe left/right.

There are **many** libraries, one of the best ones is: [react-native-snap-carousle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-snap-carousel)

Take a look at it's example:

```
import Carousel from 'react-native-snap-carousel';
 
export class MyCarousel extends Component {
 
    _renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.slide}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{ item.title }</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
 
    render () {
        return (
            <Carousel
              ref={(c) => { this._carousel = c; }}
              data={this.state.entries}
              renderItem={this._renderItem}
              sliderWidth={sliderWidth}
              itemWidth={itemWidth}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

So you can pass a screen/page as `_renderItem` to the `Carousel`

Comment: How would this approach solve the infinite screens problem? I can't populate the data prop with all the dates on the initial render, is there some way I can use generators to achieve this?

Comment: You can use FlatList to render over 10,000+ items, It uses some techniques for optimization and more. take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55256341/5737950 @Ken