# Able to type inside input text field without onChange method

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am learning React and below one is sample code I am trying out. I am able to render this component and able to type in characters in input field without any handleChange() method ?  Is this fine ?  because what I know is, in order to make input fields available for typing, we need to add handleChange method something like below

```
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
}
```

```
import React from "react";

class StudentForm extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <h1>Student Form</h1>
          <input type="text" name="firstname"></input>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default StudentForm;
```

Comment: It's controlled vs uncontrolled component. You can check the response here : components.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522515/what-are-controlled-components-and-uncontrolled-components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, consider the following

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" />
```

This is an `uncrontrolled input` which means `React` doesn't now about it's `value` nor how to change it. To make an `input` **controlled** you need to explicitly specify the `value` and `onChange` properties to bind this input to React's `state`

```
const Input = () =>{
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')

    return <input value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
}
```

Now the `input` is fully controlled by React, which provides the `value` it must print and a way to change it

Comment: Thanks man, now I understood the concept of controlled element.  You answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

`handleChange` is for setting the state value.

without onChange handler you can type in but your value is not getting stored anywhere.

For example, if you try to access your state `this.state.firstname` you will always get `undefined`.

You should have [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html). Which is a simple and cleaner way access and store value in state.

To make your component controlled, you should have `value` and `onChange` props on input,

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value={this.state.firstname} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}></input>
```

Comment: I don't think React allow us to type in as well without onchange handler right ?

Comment: @Mrbond, you can type in without onChange handler also.

Answer (score 0):

After making below changes, I made this input element as controlled element and now I am not able to type in anything without using onChange handler.

```
import React from "react";

class StudentForm extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      firstname: ""
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <h1>Student Form</h1>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="firstname"
            value={this.state.firstname}
          ></input>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default StudentForm;
```

Comment: This is because you have binded the state value to your input, now your input need onChange handler or you can make it as `defaultValue`.