# Handle multiple datepicker in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

I have implemented the datepicker and timepicker  with add,delete buttons in each row. When I click on add, will add new row and delete will delete row.

I have the code link `https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-water-tfyoz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark`
But how to handle the state for multiple datepicker and timepicker,

When change the date, it doesnot reflect the change in field. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-water-tfyoz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is in your renderRowData function:

```
<td key={`tableview-td-${rowId}-${index}`}>
  {column.dataFieldId === "pickdate" ? (
    <DatePicker
      locale="en-GB"
      className="datepicker"
      name={"pickdate_" + rowId}
      onChange={e =>
        this.handleDatePicker(
          e,
          "pickdate_" + rowId,
          column.dataFieldId,
          row
        )
      }
      value={this.state.pickdate}
    />
  )
```

For value u use this.state.pickdate, but when value changes you set it with:

```
  handleDatePicker = (value, name, field, row) => {
    this.props.handleInputChange(value, field, row);
    console.log("data", value, "for", name);
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };
```

wich means that your state is now:

```
{
   ["pickdate_" + rowId]: value // where row is selected row
}
```

you need to change your datepicker to access value like this:

```
<td key={`tableview-td-${rowId}-${index}`}>
  {column.dataFieldId === "pickdate" ? (
    <DatePicker
      locale="en-GB"
      className="datepicker"
      name={"pickdate_" + rowId}
      onChange={e =>
        this.handleDatePicker(
          e,
          "pickdate_" + rowId,
          column.dataFieldId,
          row
        )
      }
      value={this.state["pickdate_" + rowId] || this.defaultPickDate} // this will take new selected value or default if there is none
    />
  )
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-fog-1v9o3

Comment: Hi @kaca992 , I need some help, i have added additional fields in `home.js` ,  on startup it display the defaultpickdate, and when i add should display empty field, i tried changes. https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-pond-qgt5o please help

Comment: Hi @kaca992... Even I'm facing similar issue... but, its function component... unable to proceed... request you to take look into this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73826736/data-gets-updated-in-console-but-not-in-ui

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the date field's changes aren't reflected in the UI is that you've implemented it as a controlled component (you are setting the value of each DatePicker based on the corresponding value in the state and updating the state when you change the value, which effectively synchronizes the component with the state, more or less), whereas the TimePickers do change in the UI when a new time is chosen because they are implemented as uncontrolled components. Controlled components are often the best method, but your date component isn't updating on change because there are problems in your handleDatePicker function, as pointed out by Kaca992's answer.

If you don't know much about controlled vs uncontrolled components, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522515/what-are-controlled-components-and-uncontrolled-components).

As for how to handle the state for multiple DatePickers and TimePickers, personally I'd recommend that you store them as an array of rows in the state. For example, this would be a default state:

```
this.state = {
  rows: [
    {
      date: new Date(),
      start: moment(),
      end: moment(),
    }
  ]
}
```

Each row element in the array would correspond to a row in the table, and you can just use array.map to render each row as a component that contains the DatePicker, TimePickers, and buttons, and then just send the array index along with the new value to your onChange functions so that the correct row's changes can be reflected in the new state.

This would require a bit of a re-write of your DynamicDateTimePicker class, but the logic would be much simpler and more readable than how you currently have it structured.