# What are major differences between Controlled and Uncontrolled Components in react-hooks-form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I am using react hooks form. I read from documentation about controlled and uncontrolled.

**Controlled**

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <input name="firstName" ref={register({ required: true })} />
  <input name="lastName" ref={register} />
  <input type="reset" /> // standard reset button
  <input type="button" onClick={reset} />
  <input type="button" onClick={() => reset({ firstName: "bill" }); }} /> // reset form with values
  <input type="button" onClick={() => {
    reset({
      firstName: "bill"
    }, {
      errors: true, // errors will not be reset 
      dirtyFields: true, // dirtyFields will not be reset
      isDirty: true, // dirty will not be reset
      isSubmitted: false,
      touched: false,
      isValid: false,
      submitCount: false,
    });
  }} />
</form>
```

and this is **UnControlled** form

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <Controller 
    as={TextField} 
    name="firstName"
    control={control} 
    rules={ required: true } 
    defaultValue=""
  />
  <Controller 
    as={TextField} 
    name="lastName"
    control={control}
    defaultValue="" 
  />
  
  <input type="submit" />
  <input type="button" onClick={reset} />
  <input
    type="button"
    onClick={() => {
      reset({
        firstName: "bill",
        lastName: "luo"
      });
    }}
  />
</form>
```

Can somebody please tell what difference does it makes? And what do i gain by making controlled components instead of uncontrolled?

Comment: Both of those snippets seem to implement ***uncontrolled*** form inputs as their values rendered by browser are not bound to components state using `value` attribute

Comment: Regarding your question in general, you may refer to [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) they explain that in far more comprehensive manner than SO answer may possibly do.

Comment: In general, controlled input components are those whose value is driven by the state of the component in which they are defined whereas value of uncontrolled input components is not driven by the state. `react-hooks-form` library relies on uncontrolled components for performance because it reduces the amount of re-renders because of user typing in the inputs. You can implement controlled components as well with `react-hooks-form` and for that you will need to refer to the official documentation for this library.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522515/what-are-react-controlled-components-and-uncontrolled-components) may be helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

React Hook Form embraces uncontrolled form and input, which means you can still build controlled form and input as well: https://twitter.com/bluebill1049/status/1286438673546768386

so what's the difference between `ref={register}` and `Controller`?

- `ref={register}`: https://react-hook-form.com/api#register means uncontrolled input will be subscribed to the input change and retrieve its value by react-hook-form.
- `Controller`: https://react-hook-form.com/api#Controller is a wrapper component which isolating controlled component to re-render within its scope and result in less performance impact on your app/form level.