# Why input 1 value override input 2 value in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using ReactJS. In my page, I have two forms `form1` and `form2` which switches from `form1 -> form2` on state change. This state change is because of recaptcha verification  in the firebase Auth. When recaptcha verified successfully, `let [phone, setPhone] = useState(false)` state of the phone changes. If `false -> form1` & if `true->form2`.

Problem arises when I put phone number in input of form 1. After, captcha verification when form 2 render due to state change, value of input in form 2 have the default value of input of form 1.

```
let [phoneAuth, setPhoneAuth] = useState(false);
                {!phoneAuth ? 
                    <form id="123456" class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center" method="get" style={{width:"300px"}} onSubmit={formHandler}>
                        <h1 class="mb-3 h3 fw-normal">Sign In Please...</h1>
                        <input id="phone" class="rounded" type="number" placeholder="Mobile number" class="p-2" name="phone" /> <br />
                        <div id="captcha-widget"></div>
                        <button id="sign-in-button" type="submit" style={{textAlign:"center"}} class="btn btn-outline-success ">Get OTP</button>
                    </form>
                    :
                    <form id="23456" class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center" action="/" method="get" style={{width:"300px"}} onSubmit={otpHandler}>
                        <h1 class="mb-3 h3 fw-normal">Sign In</h1>
                        <input id="otp" type="number" placeholder="Enter OTP" name="otp" />
                        <button id="sign-in-button" type="submit" style={{textAlign:"center"}} class="btn btn-outline-success ">Submit OTP</button>
                    </form>
                }
```

Comment: Its because you are using `uncontrolled` way. Try with `controlled(managing inputs your own)`. Do read this for more reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522515/what-are-react-controlled-components-and-uncontrolled-components

Comment: But, Is there any way to fix this. Because, If state changes component re-render and everything reset to default values. If this happens new input value must be blank or with default value. But in my case, the new input is having value of other input element. What's going on in the background ?