# React - customers.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My problem is: when I try to change the inputs it throw customers.map is not a function. I'd like to change value and update data in the database.

```
//hook for fetching
    const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);

    //fetching data from db by id
    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/profile/${id}`)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response) {
                    setCustomers(response.data);
                }
                else {
                    alert('Error')
                }
            })
    }, [])
```

And here is how I try to map, otherwise it seems like, onChange method causes the problem.

```
    {customers.map(customer =>
        <div key={customer.id}>
            <div className="containerProfile">
                <div className="leftInputProfile">
                    <p>Full Name</p>
                    <input type="text" name='Fullname' placeholder={!customer.Fullname && "Adja meg az adatot"}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            setCustomers({ ...customers, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I know that, `.map()` method have to get an array, but I don't know the solution here :(

response.data:

[image]

Comment: what's in `response.data` ? pls attach your response as well

Comment: You should check if `response.data` is an array and from the error you see, it probably isn't.

Comment: response.data now attached

Comment: array check returned with "true" - it's an array

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in your *onChange* event you are setting your customers to an object {} which does not have the .map function by calling

```
setCustomers({ ...customers, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
```

You have to call it with brackets [] instead of curly braces {}:

```
setCustomers([ ...customers, yourNewCustomer ]);
```

Comment: okay, i'm so thankful :D it's working (.map is not a function DONE)
But i got another error....if i change value all mapped inputs are duplicated O_O

Comment: what should i write at "yourNewCostumer"?

Comment: now "yourNewCostumer" is e.target.value

Comment: I was not aware that you edit the customer, thought you wanted to add new ones. Take a look at the other answer from @Alserda, he even provided a 'updateCustomer' method, which should probably help you!

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the state to become an object:

```js
setCustomers({ ...customers, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
```

If you want to update a specific customer you could write a separate handler such as:

```
const updateCustomer = (customerId) => (event) => {
  const index = customers.findIndex((customer) => customer.id === customerId);

  const nextCustomers = customers.splice(index, 1, {
    ...customers[index],
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
  });

  setCustomers(nextCustomers);
}
```

You have to find the object to update, update it and replace it in the current state.

Your input should have at least `<input name='Fullname' onChange={updateCustomer(customer.id)} value={customer.Fullname} />`

You have to assign the `value` property too, as you're making it a [controlled component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522515/what-are-react-controlled-components-and-uncontrolled-components) with your input element.