# How to change a class based on focus and change in an input form in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, focus, onchange

I have a situation where I want to append a class called `shrink` to the label text below (Display Name) when I click or type in the input box.
My code is below:

```
const FormInput = ({ label, ...otherProps} ) => {
    let labelClassName = 'formInput-label';

    const addLabelClassName = () => {
        labelClassName = `${labelClassName} shrink`;
        console.log(labelClassName, 'labelClassName inside')
    }

    console.log(labelClassName, 'labelClassName outside')

    return (
        <div className="group">
            {label && 
                <label 
                    className={labelClassName}
                >{label}</label>
            }
            <input onFocus={addLabelClassName } onChange={addLabelClassName } className="formInput" {...otherProps} />
        </div>
    )
};
```

My question:

1. Why does when I focus/ type, at first, React outputs the correct classnames for `labelClassName inside` as `formInput-label shrink`, but immediately changes it back to `formInput-label` at the `labelClassName outside` position? How would I fix this?
2. I have also tried to change the code to using the `UseState` approach like below:

```
const FormInput = ({ label, ...otherProps} ) => {
    const [interaction, setInteraction] = useState('');
    let labelClassName = 'formInput-label';

    const onInteracting = () => {
        setInteraction('interacting')
    }

    if(interaction === 'interacting') {
        labelClassName = `${labelClassName} shrink`;
    }

    return (
        <div className="group">
            {label && 
                <label 
                    className={labelClassName}
                >{label}</label>
            }
            <input onFocus={onInteracting} onChange={onInteracting} className="formInput" {...otherProps} />
        </div>
    )
};
```

And this will append the correct class `shrink` to `labelClassName` but I'm not able to take that off when I click outside of the input/form. How may I fix this?

Thank you a ton!

Comment: Please ask one question per question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach is a better way because with changing state you will trigger component rerendering (the first approach will never re-render component).

In the second approach, you can take advantage of `onBlur` event and create a handler which will set the state to the default value. Something like this. You don't need `onChange` to setIntercation

```
...
 const handleBlur = () => {
    setInteraction("");
  };
...
```

and then in input, you have to set up `onBlur` prop. `onChange` should not do the same thing as `onFocus` already does.

```
....
 <input
        onFocus={onInteracting}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
        className="formInput"
        {...otherProps}
      />
 ....
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This solves my problem. So if I understand correctly, in my first method, I append a `shrink` class but this didn't trigger re-rendering so the class never gets applied the second time? My follow-up question is why did React console.log out  `labelClassName inside` then follows by `labelClassName outside`? Because when I look at those console logs, I thought that both are executed chronologically and didn't know that the component did not rerender.

Comment: NP I am glad I could help you. 
 `labelClassName outside` logs only on component mounting(first render) and that's it. ` labelClassName inside` logs every time onChange is triggered (every keystroke) but you have to be aware that rerender is never triggered and that's why `labelClassName outside` is never logged again.

Comment: The only reason why input element displays good value inside is that your input component is uncontrolled. Read this answer and I believe you will get the idea  behind this concept https://stackoverflow.com/a/68352693/5799742