# React warning "You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler..." when using event propagation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

An example:

```js
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState({
    name: '',
    surname: ''
  });
  const handleChange = e => {
    setUser(prev => ({...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}));
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onChange={handleChange}>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" value={user.name} />
        <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="surname" value={user.surname} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

And I get these warnings:

> Warning: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an
> `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field
> should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange`
> or `readOnly`.

Should I just ignore them?

Comment: It's exactly as the error says - what is unclear about the message?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Because I'm quite sure that my code works? There is an onChange handler in form element.

Comment: Why the ... is the question already closed. I know what controlled and uncontrolled components are, that was not my question and that doesn't answer my question. My question is about the warning and if I can safely ignore it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are React controlled components and uncontrolled components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522515/what-are-react-controlled-components-and-uncontrolled-components)

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly Thanks for researching, but that's not my question. I know what a controlled component is. I have both the onChange handler and value, I just don't put the handler in each input because that's not necessary. I know it works in vanilla javascript, and so far it also works in my react project. I just want to be sure that I haven't overlooked something regarding the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, there's nothing wrong about your code. Then yes, you can safely ignore the logs.

However, *event delegation* is not the "React way" to deal with form states, so you won't be able to get rid of those warnings.

IMHO it's not a good development experience so you could just add a `onChange={handleChange}` to each field rather than setting the `onChange` on the form. I guess that the React event system is optimized enough to not have to do event delegation, even if in your use case it was pretty convenient and elegant.

Answer (score -1):

Your OnChange needs to be in the inputs and not in the form, here is an example:

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" value={user.name} onChange={handleChangeName}/>
<input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="surname" value={user.surname} onChange={handleChangeSurName}/>
```

and this is the handle change of name

```
const handleChangeName = (e) => {
  setUser(userInfo => {...userInfo, ['name']: e.target.value})
}
```

Because you don't have onChange in your inputs, it generates this alert.