# How to prevent unnecessary component re-render in react in input field on each key stroke

Tags: react-rendering

In the code shown here, when I am trying to enter character in each input field, it constantly is re-rendering the whole component as I checked in react dev tools by highlight component while state update.

Like: username input: when I pressed "abc", it re-rendered the component 3 times. That is very bad for performance.

On each input field, I am facing this issue - how to prevent that?Can you provide a solution that I can dive deeper into that? Thanks.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  CButton,
  CCard,
  CCardBody,
  CCol,
  CContainer,
  CForm,
  CFormInput,
  CInputGroup,
  CInputGroupText,
  CRow,
} from '@coreui/react';
import CIcon from '@coreui/icons-react';
import axios from 'axios';
import InputMask from 'react-input-mask';
import { cilLocationPin, cilLockLocked, cilUser, cilPhone } from '@coreui/icons';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const UserRegister = () => {
  console.log('customer register');
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [validated, setValidate] = useState(false);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({
    userName: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    repeatPassword: '',
    location: '',
    phoneNumber: '',
  });
  const [error, setError] = useState({
    userName: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    repeatPassword: '',
    location: '',
    phoneNumber: '',
  });

  const handleInputBlur = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.currentTarget;
    if (name === 'userName' && (value.length > 20 || value.length < 5)) {
      setError((prevValues) => ({
        ...prevValues,
        [name]: 'input length between 5 to 20',
      }));
    } else if (name === 'location' && (value.length > 30 || value.length < 3)) {
      setError((prevValues) => ({
        ...prevValues,
        [name]: 'input length between 3 to 30',
      }));
    } else if (name === 'phoneNumber' && value.includes('_')) {
      setError((prevValues) => ({
        ...prevValues,
        [name]: 'input length must be 10',
      }));
    } else if (
      name === 'email' &&
      !/^([a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})$/i.test(value)
    ) {
      setError((prevValues) => ({
        ...prevValues,
        [name]: 'enter valid email address',
      }));
    } else if (name === 'password' && value.length < 8) {
      setError((prevValues) => ({
        ...prevValues,
        [name]: 'password length is very less',
      }));
    } else if (
      name === 'repeatPassword' &&
      !(
        value.length === inputValue.password.length &&
        value === document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value
      )
    ) {
      setError((prevValues) => ({
        ...prevValues,
        [name]: 'password & repeat password must be same',
      }));
    }
  };

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setInputValue((prevValues) => ({
      ...prevValues,
      [name]: value,
    }));
    if (name === 'phoneNumber' && value.includes('_')) {
      setError((prevValues) => ({
        ...prevValues,
        [name]: 'phone number length must be 10',
      }));
    } else {
      setError((prevValues) => ({
        ...prevValues,
        [name]: null,
      }));
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    if (
      inputValue.userName === '' ||
      inputValue.email === '' ||
      inputValue.password === '' ||
      inputValue.repeatPassword === '' ||
      inputValue.location === '' ||
      inputValue.phoneNumber === ''
    ) {
      setValidate(true);
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    } else {
      try {
        setValidate(true);
        const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/booking/customerRegistration';
        const response = await axios.post(url, inputValue);
        // console.log('form values', inputValue);
        if (response.status === 200) {
          window.alert('registration successful');
          console.log('inputValue', inputValue);
          navigate('/login');
        } else {
          window.alert('Email Already Exist');
          console.log(response.data);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('err', err);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="bg-light min-vh-100 d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
      <CContainer>
        <CRow className="justify-content-center">
          <CCol md={9} lg={7} xl={6}>
            <CCard className="mx-4">
              <CCardBody className="p-4">
                <CForm validated={validated}>
                  <h1>Register</h1>
                  <p className="text-medium-emphasis">Create your account</p>
                  <CInputGroup className="mb-3">
                    <CInputGroupText>
                      <CIcon icon={cilUser} />
                    </CInputGroupText>
                    <CFormInput
                      placeholder="Username"
                      name="userName"
                      value={inputValue.userName}
                      onChange={handleInputChange}
                      onBlur={handleInputBlur}
                      required
                      minLength={5}
                      maxLength={20}
                      autoComplete="username"
                      feedbackInvalid="your name is required"
                    />
                  </CInputGroup>
                  {error && error?.userName ? (
                    <div style={{ fontSize: '14px', color: '#e65a5a' }}>{error?.userName}</div>
                  ) : (
                    ''
                  )}
                  <CInputGroup className="mb-3">
                    <CInputGroupText>@</CInputGroupText>
                    <CFormInput
                      placeholder="Email"
                      type="email"
                      name="email"
                      value={inputValue.email}
                      onChange={handleInputChange}
                      onBlur={handleInputBlur}
                      required
                      autoComplete="email"
                      feedbackInvalid="email is required"
                    />
                  </CInputGroup>
                  {error && error?.email ? (
                    <div style={{ fontSize: '14px', color: '#e65a5a' }}>{error?.email}</div>
                  ) : (
                    ''
                  )}
                  <CInputGroup className="mb-3">
                    <CInputGroupText>
                      <CIcon icon={cilLockLocked} />
                    </CInputGroupText>
                    <CFormInput
                      type="password"
                      name="password"
                      placeholder="Password"
                      autoComplete="new-password"
                      value={inputValue.password}
                      minLength={8}
                      onChange={handleInputChange}
                      onBlur={handleInputBlur}
                      feedbackInvalid="password is required"
                      required
                    />
                  </CInputGroup>
                  {error && error?.password ? (
                    <div style={{ fontSize: '14px', color: '#e65a5a' }}>{error?.password}</div>
                  ) : (
                    ''
                  )}
                  <CInputGroup className="mb-4">
                    <CInputGroupText>
                      <CIcon icon={cilLockLocked} />
                    </CInputGroupText>
                    <CFormInput
                      type="password"
                      name="repeatPassword"
                      placeholder="Repeat password"
                      autoComplete="new-password"
                      value={inputValue.repeatPassword}
                      minLength={8}
                      maxLength={inputValue.password.length}
                      onChange={handleInputChange}
                      onBlur={handleInputBlur}
                      feedbackInvalid="repeat password is required"
                      required
                    />
                  </CInputGroup>
                  {error && error?.repeatPassword ? (
                    <div style={{ fontSize: '14px', color: '#e65a5a' }}>
                      {error?.repeatPassword}
                    </div>
                  ) : (
                    ''
                  )}
                  <CInputGroup className="mb-3">
                    <CInputGroupText>
                      <CIcon icon={cilLocationPin} />
                    </CInputGroupText>
                    <CFormInput
                      placeholder="Location"
                      name="location"
                      value={inputValue.location}
                      onChange={handleInputChange}
                      onBlur={handleInputBlur}
                      minLength={3}
                      maxLength={30}
                      feedbackInvalid="location is required"
                      required
                      autoComplete="location"
                    />
                  </CInputGroup>
                  {error && error?.location ? (
                    <div style={{ fontSize: '14px', color: '#e65a5a' }}>{error?.location}</div>
                  ) : (
                    ''
                  )}
                  <CInputGroup className="mb-3">
                    <CInputGroupText>
                      <CIcon icon={cilPhone} />
                    </CInputGroupText>
                    <InputMask
                      mask="99999-99999"
                      maskChar="_"
                      value={inputValue.phoneNumber}
                      onChange={handleInputChange}
                      onBlur={handleInputBlur}
                      required
                    >
                      {(inputProps) => (
                        <CFormInput
                          type="text"
                          id="phoneNumber"
                          name="phoneNumber"
                          placeholder="Enter Phone Number"
                          {...inputProps}
                          feedbackInvalid={'phone number is required'}
                        />
                      )}
                    </InputMask>
                  </CInputGroup>
                  {error && error?.phoneNumber ? (
                    <div style={{ fontSize: '14px', color: '#e65a5a' }}>{error?.phoneNumber}</div>
                  ) : (
                    ''
                  )}
                  <div className="d-grid">
                    <CButton color="success" type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                      Create Account
                    </CButton>
                  </div>
                </CForm>
              </CCardBody>
            </CCard>
          </CCol>
        </CRow>
      </CContainer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserRegister;
```

Comment: You can create another component for fields and handle onChange within the component. You can pass final value to the parent component  on onBlur.

Answer (score 0):

A few options that you can look into:

1. Isolate the input component
   Put the input component into a child component, and put all the logic for input inside of that component, this way only the child component will rerender
2. Use `useRef` instead of `useState`
   Change in `ref` will not cause rerenders
   https://codedamn.com/news/reactjs/a-comprehensive-guide-to-using-useref-hook
3. Use debounce method
   Debouncing is removing unwanted input noise from buttons, switches or other user input. Debouncing prevents extra activations or slow functions from triggering too often.
   https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-debounce-method/

Comment: if i use useRef then how will it update the state? becasue it is preserving the value. so how can i see my entered character in input field. - as of my knowledge.

Comment: @AmanSheth Yes, that's correct, that would mean you're attempting to use uncontrolled input. So instead of passing in `value` to the input, you can use `defaultValue`, this will cause the input to be uncontrolled

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a state, we should consider using the `useRef()` hook which will allow us to access the input field's value directly.

In this case, we can create `ref` for each input field and after that, we can access the values using `ref.current.value`, and if you need to manually need to update the value just use `ref.current.value = 'Any value goes here'`.

Comment: if i use useRef then how will it update the state? becasue it is preserving the value. so how can i see my entered character in input field. - as of my knowledge.

Comment: We have a concept of controlled and uncontrolled components. you can find a better explanation here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522515/what-are-react-controlled-components-and-uncontrolled-components